# Overriding model file is not working in Magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento2, overrides, catalog, magento-2.2.5

I tried to override model, but it is not working. I need to override:

> Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Price to
>   Pawan\Catalog\Model\Rewrite\Product\Attribute\Backend\Price

But it not working.

My `di.xml` path `Pawan/Catalog/etc/di.xml`:

> `<?xml version="1.0"?>
>   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
>       <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Price" typr="Pawan\Catalog\Model\Rewrite\Product\Attribute\Backend\Price" />
>   </config>`

My model file:

```
<?php
    namespace Pawan\Catalog\Model\Rewrite\Product\Attribute\Backend;

    class Price extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Price
    {
        public function afterSave($object)
        {
            $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/importmissingorders.log');
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            $logger->info("custom model");

            /** @var $attribute \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute */
            $attribute = $this->getAttribute();
            $attributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
            $value = $object->getData($attributeCode);

            // $value may be passed as null to unset the attribute
            if ($value === null || (float)$value > 0) {
                if ($attribute->isScopeWebsite() && $object->getStoreId() != \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID) {
                    if ($this->isUseDefault($object)) {
                        $value = null;
                    }
                    foreach ((array)$object->getWebsiteStoreIds() as $storeId) {
                        $object->addAttributeUpdate($attributeCode, $value, $storeId);
                    }
                }
            }
            return $this;
        }
    }
```

It is still executing the core file only.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you already clear cache or setup:upgrade or di:compile ?

Comment: What do you mean by *"But it working."* and *"My `di.xml` local `Pawan/Catalog/etc/di.xml`"*?

Answer (score 5):

Change `typr`,

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Price" typr="Pawan\Catalog\Model\Rewrite\Product\Attribute\Backend\Price" />
```

to `type`:

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Price" type="Pawan\Catalog\Model\Rewrite\Product\Attribute\Backend\Price" />
```

Comment: yes in server logs i found it typo mistake